# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on rubygem installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew, rbenv

While trying to do "bundle install",  I receive error message below

> environment = **OSX 10.9.4**, **rbenv 0.4.0**,
>   **ruby 2.1.2**,
>   **Homebrew 0.9.5**

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
/Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1573:in `stat': No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - ./212/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1573:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1587:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:399:in `cp'
    from extconf.rb:83:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/debugger-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/hirotakagotanda/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/debugger-1.6.6/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Could anyone please provide me solution, I have been misfortunate to find out any...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem with the Xcode Command Line Tools.  There are a number of steps needed to get this right.

This question [Installing Ruby Debug IDE Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459937/installing-ruby-debug-ide-gem) provides one example.

Comment: I tried above and also "gem install debugger -v '1.6.6'" but yet to succeed the installation....

Comment: I had this problem and tried a lot of different approaches. I'll see if I can find my notes on this, it was very frustrating.

Comment: any leads on the question?

Comment: This didn't fix it for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by agreeing to xcode's license (it seems to happen after an update and you haven't yet agreed to the update)

Just run `xcodebuild -license` from the command line

Found the answer thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653546/gemextbuilderror-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-archlinux) question

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above comments helped me.  Changing to ruby 2.1.1 of below allowed me to bundle without issue.

```
rbenv local 2.1.1
bundle install
```

using ruby 2.1.2, it breaks in the same place

Comment: I am using OSX 10.10, but the same versions of rbenv and homebrew