# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. Archlinux

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to run jekyll locally on my laptop.
I followed the guide of Github to do that, https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages 
Unfortunaly I'm stuck when I have typed
    $bundle install
I get the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........Failed to load /etc/gemrc due to permissions problem.
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
--with-redcloth_scan-dir
--without-redcloth_scan-dir
--with-redcloth_scan-include
--without-redcloth_scan-include=${redcloth_scan-dir}/include
--with-redcloth_scan-lib
--without-redcloth_scan-lib=${redcloth_scan-dir}/lib
--with-clib
--without-clib
 /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an         executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:742:in `try_func'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:973:in `block in have_library'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:968:in `have_library'
from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20140903-2231-pkzqqj/RedCloth-4.2.9/gems /RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20140903-2231-pkzqqj/RedCloth-4.2.9/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/RedCloth-4.2.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tryed to install ruby multiple times but it's not solving my problem. Do you have any hints?

Comment: I would install ruby using rvm and then check `rvm requirements` to install any packages that are needed. You seem to be missing some dev packages.

Comment: $ rvm requirements
    Checking requirements for arch.
    Requirements installation successful. It does not help unfortunaly.

Comment: How about `pacman -S base-devel`?

Comment: It doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem on MacOS and it was fixed by agreeing to the Xcode License. I had recently updated Xcode and it turns out that I needed to re-agree to the license in order to use the command line tools successfully.

Just run:

```
xcodebuild -license
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install qt
```

then

```
gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'
```

then

```
bundle install
```